# Sitecore - Programatically modify the source field of a template

Tags: c#, sitecore

Currently, all the templates that we have created have source fields whose path is a string.

e.g. :

`"sitecore/content/Test"`

Now if I want to move the Test folder to

```
sitecore/content/Shared/Tags/Test
```

the links are broken.
If i manually change this to use the GUID (Using the build option), I get :

```
datasource={62CF8494-B148-4B2E-9D36-52EC4CD75E13}&database=master
```

If i now move the test folder around, my links remain as is.

I wanted to write a routine that runs through the tree and updates all the source fields for my templates (in a particular folder only), to contain the GUID and db name.
Is this possible?

I tried doing this in the Process method of a class that inherits from PublishItemProcessor and added the appropriate entry in the web.config. This method is called, but the Source property of the field is read only and cannpt be modified.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance you can provide an example of what you ended up with? Would love to add it to the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best/most efficient option here would be to use Sitecore Powershell Extensions to modify the items.

This is a good reference point: https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/working-with-items.html

You could also do this in code.

You need to write a routine (code or SPE) that starts with the `/sitecore/templates/user defined` or whatever your root folder is.

Recurse thru the tree and get all items that have the template: `Template Field`. Then you can check value of the the `Source` field. If it is the one you want to change, update the value and save the item.

Remember to publish the templates tree after updating all the values.